# What does the question mark in java mean?

Tags: java

I have encounter a code snippt

```
putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map)
```

on the [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html) site, I know that the **K** and **V** are placeholders, but what does the question mark **?** mean? Does it mean that the param must be a reference type or something else?

Comment: Read about Java generics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java **`?`** is known as Wildcard, you can use it to respresent an `unknown type`.

> The upper bounded wildcard, , where Foo is any type, matches Foo and any subtype of Foo. The process method can access the list elements as type Foo:

```
public static void process(Map<? extends A> list) {
  /* code */
}
```

In your case it is known as Upper bounded wildcard.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

```
putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map)
```

It means, that any object, that can extend the `A` class is applicable in this conditionn.

Comment: By A do you mean Foo?

Comment: @twlkyao No, `Foo` is just a class used as `ExampleClass` :) Don't confuse it with A. :)

Comment: I mean I can't find the A in your post nor the link.

Comment: There you go. I removed the ambiguity. :) @twlkyao

Answer (score 5):

It's a wild card for class type, in your case

```
putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map)
```

the first question mark indicates that any type which extends K is applicable, and so on.

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)